# Error migrating the wordpress on developing

Tags: wordpress, migrate

I'm developing a WordPress page on local, now i need to migrate it to a server.

I did it before 2 or 3 times some time ago, i move the files to the new server, change the URL on the database entries and create the new database.

I had problems establishing problems to database cause a letter missing on the `db_name`. and i was getting the **"connecting to database error"**. I fixed it, but now, when i load the page, navigator show me.

> ¡Ouch! Google Chrome cant establish a conection with the page
>   preview.mypage.com:8887.

I think about something is bad about **:8887** because i work in basic php before...but don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem on `wp-options`

Site URL and Home entries don't actualize their values then i did the replace on the `.sql` with a text editor.

Wish this help other people.